# Script sorting by text in checkboxes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, smarty

Good afternoon. Can you please tell me why the script for sorting by text in the checkbox does not work if the checkboxes are displayed through foreach in smarty?

Foreach displays checkboxes in which the text is located. By default they are sorted by id, but I need them to be sorted by text (cyrillic). For this I use a script. But for some reason it does not work with foreach, without foreach it works

With foeach script does not sort:

```
   {foreach name=Arr key=cid item=val from=$ArrTipkat}

  {if $smarty.foreach.Arr.first}    
<div id="DivTipkatCheckboxList">     
  {/if}

  <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[{$val.tipkat_id}]" id="TipkatCheckbox{$val.tipkat_id}" value="{$val.tipkat_id}"{if in_array ($val.tipkat_id, $ArrTipkatByDefault)} checked="checked"{/if} />&nbsp; {$val.tipkat_name}<br />
  </label>

    {if $smarty.foreach.Arr.last}      
</div>
    {/if}

{/foreach}

<script>
    var sortByText = function (a, b) {         
        return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var sorted = $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList label' ).sort(sortByText);
        $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList').append(sorted); 
   });
  </script>
```

And without foreach, the script works and the checkboxes are sorted by text, here:

```js
    var sortByText = function (a, b) {
       // console.log($.trim($(a).text()));
        return $.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text());
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var sorted = $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList label' ).sort(sortByText);
        $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList').append(sorted);          

    });
```

```css
.subMenue {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivTipkatCheckboxList">

  <h3 style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#section1">Перечень БД для поиска</a></h3>

  
      <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[3]" id="TipkatCheckbox3" value="3" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические кодексы установившейся практики<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[5]" id="TipkatCheckbox5" value="5" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические условия<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[6]" id="TipkatCheckbox6" value="6" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Авиационные правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[7]" id="TipkatCheckbox7" value="7" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Зоотехнические правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[8]" id="TipkatCheckbox8" value="8" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Санитарные нормы и правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[9]" id="TipkatCheckbox9" value="9" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Нормы и правила пожарной безопасности<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[10]" id="TipkatCheckbox10" value="10" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Нормы и правила по обеспечению технической, промышленной, ядерной и радиационной безопасности<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[11]" id="TipkatCheckbox11" value="11" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Правила по обеспечению безопасности перевозки опасных грузов<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[12]" id="TipkatCheckbox12" value="12" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Нормы и правила рационального использования и охраны недр<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[13]" id="TipkatCheckbox13" value="13" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Квалификационные справочники<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[15]" id="TipkatCheckbox15" value="15" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Формы государственных статистических наблюдений и указания по их заполнению<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[16]" id="TipkatCheckbox16" value="16" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Методики по формированию и расчету статистических показателей<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[17]" id="TipkatCheckbox17" value="17" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Инструкции по организации и проведению государственных статистических наблюдений<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[18]" id="TipkatCheckbox18" value="18" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Формы ведомственной отчетности и указания по их заполнению<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[19]" id="TipkatCheckbox19" value="19" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Проекты зон охраны недвижимых материальных историко-культурных ценностей<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[20]" id="TipkatCheckbox20" value="20" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Геодезические, картографические нормы и правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[23]" id="TipkatCheckbox23" value="23" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Национальные стандарты Российской Федерации<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[24]" id="TipkatCheckbox24" value="24" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Международные стандарты Комиссии Кодекс Алиментариус<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[25]" id="TipkatCheckbox25" value="25" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Документы Всемирной организации по охране здоровья животных<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[26]" id="TipkatCheckbox26" value="26" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Международные стандарты на фитосанитарные меры<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[27]" id="TipkatCheckbox27" value="27" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Рекомендации Международного союза электросвязи ITU<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[28]" id="TipkatCheckbox28" value="28" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Международные стандарты по безопасности МАГАТЭ<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[29]" id="TipkatCheckbox29" value="29" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Документы Глобального кодекса надлежащей практики в сельском хозяйстве<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[30]" id="TipkatCheckbox30" value="30" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Документы ФАО<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[31]" id="TipkatCheckbox31" value="31" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Техническое законодательство ЕС<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[32]" id="TipkatCheckbox32" value="32" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Комитета по торговле ЕЭК ООН<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[33]" id="TipkatCheckbox33" value="33" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Международной организации по стандартизации ISO<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[34]" id="TipkatCheckbox34" value="34" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Международной электротехнической комиссии IEC<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[35]" id="TipkatCheckbox35" value="35" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Европейского комитета по стандартизации CEN<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[36]" id="TipkatCheckbox36" value="36" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Европейского комитета по стандартизации в электротехнике CENELEC<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[37]" id="TipkatCheckbox37" value="37" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Стандарты Европейского института по стандартизации в области электросвязи<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[38]" id="TipkatCheckbox38" value="38" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Документы Европейской организации по сотрудничеству в области аккредитации<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[44]" id="TipkatCheckbox44" value="44" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты ЕАЭС (ТС)<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[60]" id="TipkatCheckbox60" value="60" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Республики Армения<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[61]" id="TipkatCheckbox61" value="61" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Российской Федерации<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[62]" id="TipkatCheckbox62" value="62" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Республики Казахстан<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[63]" id="TipkatCheckbox63" value="63" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Республики Молдова<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[64]" id="TipkatCheckbox64" value="64" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Кыргызской Республики<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[66]" id="TipkatCheckbox66" value="66" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Украины<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[72]" id="TipkatCheckbox72" value="72" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Документы ЕАЭС (ТС)<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[81]" id="TipkatCheckbox81" value="81" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Межгосударственные стандарты<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[85]" id="TipkatCheckbox85" value="85" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Национальные стандарты Республики Казахстан<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[86]" id="TipkatCheckbox86" value="86" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Республики Таджикистан<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[88]" id="TipkatCheckbox88" value="88" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Статистические классификаторы<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[92]" id="TipkatCheckbox92" value="92" />&nbsp; Издания<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[94]" id="TipkatCheckbox94" value="94" />&nbsp; Образовательные стандарты<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[95]" id="TipkatCheckbox95" value="95" />&nbsp; ТНПА, являющиеся структурными элементами научно-методического обеспечения образования<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[97]" id="TipkatCheckbox97" value="97" />&nbsp; Клинические протоколы<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[98]" id="TipkatCheckbox98" value="98" />&nbsp; Экологические нормы и правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[99]" id="TipkatCheckbox99" value="99" />&nbsp; Документы Европейской организации по аккредитации<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[100]" id="TipkatCheckbox100" value="100" />&nbsp; Общегосударственные классификаторы Республики Беларусь<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[101]" id="TipkatCheckbox101" value="101" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Государственные стандарты Республики Беларусь<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[102]" id="TipkatCheckbox102" value="102" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Технические регламенты Республики Беларусь<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[103]" id="TipkatCheckbox103" value="103" />&nbsp; Национальные стандарты Республики Армения, Кыргызской Республики под ТР ЕАЭС (ТС)<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[104]" id="TipkatCheckbox104" value="104" />&nbsp; НПА об утверждении, внесении изменений и отмене ТНПА<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[106]" id="TipkatCheckbox106" value="106" />&nbsp; Фармакопейные статьи<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[107]" id="TipkatCheckbox107" value="107" />&nbsp; Правила технической эксплуатации железной дороги<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[108]" id="TipkatCheckbox108" value="108" />&nbsp; Ветеринарно-санитарные правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[109]" id="TipkatCheckbox109" value="109" />&nbsp; Зоогигиенические правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[110]" id="TipkatCheckbox110" value="110" />&nbsp; Требования по оформлению квалификационных научных работ (диссертаций) и авторефератов<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[111]" id="TipkatCheckbox111" value="111" />&nbsp; Нормы бесплатной выдачи работникам средств индивидуальной защиты, смывающих и обезвреживающих средств<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[112]" id="TipkatCheckbox112" value="112" />&nbsp; Правила и инструкции по охране труда<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[113]" id="TipkatCheckbox113" value="113" />&nbsp; Стандарты проведения расчетов<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[114]" id="TipkatCheckbox114" value="114" />&nbsp; Проекты водоохранных зон и прибрежных полос<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[115]" id="TipkatCheckbox115" value="115" />&nbsp; Градостроительные проекты детального планирования<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[116]" id="TipkatCheckbox116" value="116" />&nbsp; Гигиенические нормативы<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[119]" id="TipkatCheckbox119" value="119" />&nbsp; Схемы землеустройства<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[120]" id="TipkatCheckbox120" value="120" />&nbsp; Структуры и форматы электронных документов<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[122]" id="TipkatCheckbox122" value="122" />&nbsp; Статистические индексы стоимости и индексы изменения стоимости строительно-монтажных работ<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[124]" id="TipkatCheckbox124" value="124" />&nbsp; Строительные правила<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[127]" id="TipkatCheckbox127" value="127" />&nbsp; Строительные нормы<br />
    </label>
          <label>
   <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="TipkatCheckbox[130]" id="TipkatCheckbox130" value="130" />&nbsp; Нормативы расхода ресурсов в строительстве<br />
    </label>
    <!--    <hr class="MsThemeHrC MsThemeHrT" />
    <input class="MsUsersSettings" type="checkbox" name="OurDocsCheckbox" id="OurDocsCheckbox" value="1" />&nbsp;Наши документы<br />-->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should sort your list. I added a line that will clear the content from the section before re-adding all the checkboxes, this should prevent duplicate values.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var sorted = $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList label' ).sort(sortByText);

       $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList').html(''); //clear section
       for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
           $('#DivTipkatCheckboxList').append(sorted[i].innerHTML);
       }

   });
```